# Customer order restrictions

Tags: magento-1.7, customer, magento-community, magento-ce

I want to restrict no of orders by customer to 99 per month and the total amount limit to $500 per month.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you will need to create an extension with an observer that watches for the quote_totals, something like the following: http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/tag/event-observer/

This will need to check against your conditions and probably prompt the user in some way.

Another option would be to do it at the template and/or block level. Checking against the conditions there may be easier to implement, but would not be as future-proof.